# Chrome Dev Tools Request Cancelled | Release Build

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, ionic-framework, ionic2

In my Ionic App, when I create a Debug APK with `cordova build` I can without a problem connect to the Server and login. The Dev-Tools from Chrome show me, that the Request returns 200 and everything works fine.

However once I make a Release APK with `cordova build --release` I instantly get an Error when trying to login. In the Network Tab I then see that the Request got cancelled, without any Message or Information why, or what went wrong.

What is the difference between the release and the debug apk? How can I investigate why the Request gets cancelled?

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: have you found any solution or workarround?

Comment: Facing the same problem.